# How to rotate a quanternion and calculate direction vector in Unity (ECS)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I started to work with ECS and I have a Rotation component (quaternion) and a Translation component (float3). I am writing a System that will handle user input and rotate and/or move forward the player.

The problem is I don't know how to do it. The existing API is lacking in my opinion.

```
// Before it was easy
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    var newPostion = new Vector3(player.Position.x, player.Position.y, 0.3f)
                    + _playerTransform.up * Time.deltaTime * PlayerSpeed;

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    _playerTransform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, PlayerRotationFactor));

// now it is not - that's part of the system's code
Entities.With(query).ForEach((Entity entity, ref Translation translation, ref Rotation rotation) =>
{
    float3 tmpTranslation = translation.Value;
    quaternion tmpRotation = rotation.Value;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        // how to retrieve forward vector from the quaternion
        tmpTranslation.y += Time.deltaTime * PlayerSpeed; 

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        // this always set the same angle
        tmpRotation = quaternion.RotateZ(PlayerRotationFactor); 

    // ECS need this
    var newTranslation = new Translation { Value = tmpTranslation };
    PostUpdateCommands.SetComponent(entity, newTranslation);
    var newRotation = new Rotation { Value = tmpRotation };
    PostUpdateCommands.SetComponent(entity, newRotation);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the vector from a quaternion you can simply multiply it with a forward vector, example:

```cs
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
{
    Vector forward = tmpRotation * float3(0,0,1);
    tmpTranslation += forward * Time.deltaTime * PlayerSpeed;
}
```

For the rotation part, as you say `// this always set the same angle`. Looks like you're creating a new angle of static degree. Try change to multiply with the current angle, as with quaternions you multiply to combine. Example:

```cs
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
{
    tmpRotation = mul(tmpRotation, quaternion.RotateZ(PlayerRotationFactor));
}
```

Sidenote: I'm also a bit new to Unity ECS, and I've not tested above codes.

Comment: You are a mathematical genius mister!!
The answer is 100% correct. Below the code adjusted to match the naming of existing API.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
// correct forward
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
{
    float3 forwardVector = math.mul(rotation.Value, new float3(0, 1, 0));
    newTranslation += forwardVector * Time.deltaTime * PlayerSpeed;
}
// correct rotation
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
{
    quaternion newRotation = math.mul(rotation.Value, quaternion.RotateZ(PlayerRotationFactor * Time.deltaTime));
    // insert new value to the component
    PostUpdateCommands.SetComponent(entity, new Rotation { Value = newRotation });
}
// thx akaJag
```

Answer (score 1):

## NOTICE to other viewers.

That code does not use the delegate variable references as they should be.

Setting the component in `PostUpdateCommands` (or `EntityManager`, or any other `CommandBufferSystem`) is utterly unnecessary as the translation / rotation is directly present - in the delegate function - to be manipulated by ref.

AKA:

```
rotation.Value = newRotation
translation.Value = newTranslation
```

**NOT**

```
EntityManager(CommandBuffer).SetComponentData(entity, new Rotation{ Value = newRotation})
```